# Spring - LDAP Authentication - password encoder for CRYPT-MD5 passwords

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users using LDAP in Spring Boot. This is my Web Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://my.ldap.url/dc=mysite,dc=com")
        .and()
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

Using Apache Directory Studio I can see that the password encryption method is `CRYPT-MD5`. I used the LdapShaPasswordEncoder as password encoder as I did not know exactly which encoder I should use. I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` error when trying to login.
I assume I have chosen the wrong encoder. Does anybody know which encoder should I use?